# How to get Track Duration for Spotify using Spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I've been playing around with Spotify API in Python (Spotipy) and I don't know how to get the duration of the track I'm currently playing on Spotify.
I'm assuming it would look something like this:

```
global spotifyObject
trackInfo = spotifyObject.current_user_playing_track()

// would probably look something like this?
trackInfo['duration']
```

I suppose it would be a dictionary because `trackInfo['currently_playing_type'] == 'ad'` worked successfully. After taking some time searching through the Spotipy documentation and guessing a few keywords, I still did not hit the bullseye.

In Android Java Spotify API, it was actually pretty straight forward:

```
mSpotifyAppRemote.getPlayerApi()
            .subscribeToPlayerState()
            .setEventCallback(playerState -> {
                final Track track = playerState.track;
                String trackName = track.name;
                // here!
                Long trackDuration = track.duration;
                });
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Thank you!

Comment: Try `trackInfo['duration_ms']`

Comment: it says `trackInfo['duration_ms']` throws a `KeyError: 'duration_ms'` when i print it out

Comment: Try to print what trackInfo has

Comment: That's what it said ^ 
Your suggestion is missing`['item']` before accessing the nested items in the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_user_playing_track` gets in response a json like this:

```
{
  [...] # [...] means i've deleted a portion to keep the code short
  "progress_ms": 5465,
  "item": {
    "album": [...]
    "artists": [...]
    "disc_number": 1,
    "duration_ms": 163294,
    "explicit": false
    },
  },
  "currently_playing_type": "track",
  "actions": {
    "disallows": {
      "pausing": true,
      "skipping_prev": true
    }
  },
  "is_playing": false
}
```

as we can see `"duration_ms"` is inside `"item"`, so to access it you need to do

```
trackInfo['item']["duration_ms"]
```

The spotify developer console might be helpful for cases like this: https://developer.spotify.com/console/get-users-currently-playing-track/